# How to show git changes pushed in the last 24 hours?

Tags: git, git-log

I'm familiar with the syntax for `git log --since="24 hours ago"` which shows changes that were **committed** (to the authors local repository) in the last 24 hours.

We have a team of developers who are constantly committing locally, and then only pushing those changes every two days or so.  If this is true, then `git log --since="24 hours ago"` will never list those changes.  (we're using this for nightly summary e-mails)

What I'd really like to see is: Changes that have been pushed to master in the last 24 hours, and be able to do this without having to manually remember the commit hash of the last time that our summarization script ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` itself doesn't track metadata for when things are pushed/pulled. As noted in the answer from user4815162342, there are some things that can be correlated to guess (reflogs, timestamps on files, etc.), but that's not a perfect solution. If you're using `git daemon`, it can be set up to log each connection, and your web server can do the same for http/https connections. You could also set up some hooks (specifically the pre-recieve or post-recieve ones) to capture some information for you as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a command like this, running it on the server to which your developers are pushing:

```
git reflog master --since="24 hours ago"
```

Unfortunately, this information doesn't appear to be transferred by `git fetch` and similar commands, and running `git reflog origin/master` locally retrieves the history of *pulls* from the hub.